# Error con Shutil de Python al copiar y mover archivos a otra ruta

Tags: python

estoy intentando usar la libreria Shutil para mover un archivo a una carpeta diferente pero marca error, estoy usando un codigo que vi en varias paginas y algunos videos pero no se que hago mal al realizar estos pasos, podrian ayudarme?

```
import shutil
shutil.move('\Users\ecastrop\Desktop\archivo1.xlsx','\Users\ecastrop\Desktop\Reporte people+')
```

No se que estoy haciendo mal, por favor necesito su ayuda

Comment: Hola Edher ¿Que error te da?

Comment: Hola que tal, me aparece el siguiente error:        File "C:\Users\ecastrop\Documents\Python Bot\importar_archivos.py", line 3
    shutil.move("\Users\ecastrop\Desktop\CV Edher Castro Pot.pdf","\Users\ecastrop\Desktop\Reporte people+")
                ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
[Finished in 0.2s]

Comment: No uses jamás `  \ ` sola en una cadena que  especifique una ruta, usa ` / ` que es universal. `  \ ` se usa para especificar secuencias de escape como la tabulación `\t`, carácter de nueva linea `\n`, etc. Aunque se puede usar ` \\  ` (escapar el carácter ' \ ') o cadenas crudas `r"\ruta\a\"`` no te lo recomiendo, fallan en ciertas situaciones.

Comment: Te lo suuuuuuper agradezco!!! llevaba casi todo el dia intentando ver mi error, soy muy nuevo en esto de la programacion y mas aun con python, nuevamente lo agradezco mucho